# Высчитать новые координаты после поворота холста

Tags: любой-язык, геометрия

В общем, дан некий холст от которого известна его ширина и высота.
На него нанесена фигура, которая имеет X,Y, ширина высота.

Холст поворачивается на 90 градусов либо в 1 сторону либо.

И вот мне нужно получить новые координаты этой фигуры(Розовая на скриншоте), что бы разместить ее на холсте в правильном месте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал пытаться выводить формулу сам, но мне кажется, что я изобретаю велосипед и уже есть готовое решение...

С использыванием каких формул я это могу сделать?

Comment: тригонометрических, очевидно, что в случае поворота на 90 градусов, весьма недурно упрощается. неужели по запросу "поворот вокруг точки" ничего не нашлось?

Comment: поворот вокруг начала координат - https://excel2.ru/sites/default/files/transform-6.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если я правильно понял, то новый прямоугольник должен высчитываться так? `new Rectangle((int)(rect.X*Math.Cos(90)- rect.Y * Math.Sin(90)), (int)(rect.X * Math.Sin(90) + rect.Y * Math.Cos(90)),  rect.Width, rect.Height);`

Comment: @iluxa1810 необходимо пересчитать все 4 точки исходного прямоугольника, и учите что это поворот вокруг точки 0,0 а не вокруг центра большого прямоугольника, т.е. перед поворотом надо сдвинуть центр большого прямоугольника в координаты 0,0, а после поворота - обратно, почитайте про  матрицу аффинных преобразований

Comment: @StrangerintheQ А в .NET есть чего-нибудь готовое, что бы я вбил туда данные, а на выходе получил новый "малый" прямоугольник, который мог бы разместить в правильном положении на большом?

Comment: @AlexF ну эта штука, как я понимаю, работает с графическими объектами. А у меня просто прямоугольник.

Comment: новые координаты относительно какого начала координат вам надо получить?